# Why am I not getting the +2 points when I edit questions after I've earned "edit questions and answers" privilege?

Tags: support

Since I got "edit questions and answers" privilege

[image]

I'm not getting points when I edit or improve questions.

Check out my Revisions list:

[image]

and my Reputation list:

[image]

You can notice that I haven't earned the +2 from any of the above edits.

I know that there is a limit to gain reputation from edits:

- You suggest an edit and it is approved: +2 (**up to a total of +1000
  per user**)
- You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested
  edits in any given day.

but non of this is true in my case, I checked out my reputation (https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and I got this data:

days represented 54

- rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
- earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days
- earned 24 reputation from suggested edits

When you earned the privilege: "Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately", Do you lose the reward points or there is something that I'm missing.

So basically my question is why I am not earning points from edits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because that's just how it works. When you hit 2000 rep, you can make edits without review/approval, and you no longer earn rep for approved edits (because you aren't going through the approval process).

Comment: That info should be added to the help center page on reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @BSMP That page says: "suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)".  There is no mention of reputation awarded for edits that are not suggested.

Comment: @BSMP It's also rather obvious if you think about it. If the system kept awarding points for any unapproved edit, you could technically just go editing posts and saving them with no change for free rep. And it's rather obvious that the system isn't gonna hand out free rep.

Comment: I particularly do editions for a better Q&A system but it would be good to have a little reward for your work as SO currently say "Helping others is its own reward. But you can't *wear* pride".  I know some might take advantage of this, but I do not think removing +2 is the solution, it is probably better to have a queue of "made reviews" and if you see any wrong or unnecessary edit yo could penalize with -10 pts to the user who made it maybe by open voting, I'm pretty sure that anyone who makes an edition for +2 was going to risk to lose 10.

Comment: @Jan - That doesn't mean the help documentation should be incomplete. There's no real reason that *"suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user) "* can't say *suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user for users with less than 2000)*.

Comment: @BSMP: The documentation is in no way incomplete. It spells it out right there: "**suggested edit is accepted**". With 2k, you don't suggest edits anymore (except to tag wikis, which your proposed text would actually be misleading on without further tweaks).